# Using Delimiters in DB-Fiddle (MySQL 8.0)

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-8.0

I'm trying to create a stored procedure on db-fiddle.com (https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/qMPGptFmKSNMJartC8yMfD/1), and I'm having trouble figuring out what to do with my DELIMITER statement.

I've built the tables and stored procedure code on the Schema side, and I'm trying to call the stored procedure from the Query side.

```
DELIMITER //          
CREATE PROCEDURE conservation_count (IN con INT)
BEGIN
   DECLARE ytotal INT;
   SET ytotal := 0;
   SET ytotal := (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Species, Animals
              WHERE Species.ID = Animals.species
              AND Species.ConservationStatus = con);
   SELECT ytotal;
   INSERT INTO conservation_ct VALUES (ytotal);
END //     
DELIMITER;
```

This is the schema error that db-fiddle is sending back:

```
Schema Error: Error: ER_PARSE_ERROR: You have an error in your SQL syntax; 
check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '// DELIMITER' at line 10
```

Comment: . . That's a good question.  I find rextester easier for this purpose.

Comment: Nothing seems to be wrong with the syntax.  It is the fiddle that seems to have issues.

Comment: Seem you don't need to use `DELIMITER` on db-fiddle website

Answer (score 1):

So after more testing, there were two things happening:

1. My last DELIMITER needed a space between DELIMITER and ; - that was likely causing the DELIMITER error
2. DB-Fiddle did not like my stored procedure. When I took out the internal variables and simplified it, it works perfectly:

   ```
   DELIMITER //
   CREATE PROCEDURE conservation_count (IN var1 INT)
   BEGIN
   SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Species, Animals WHERE Species.ID = Animals.species 
   AND Species.ConservationStatus = var1 ;
   END //
   DELIMITER ;
   ```